# Writing an insert method for a binary search tree

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement the methods to create a binary search tree in Java that will eventually be able to create a word-reference report.

My problem is I can't get my `insertItem` method to compile properly.

The the line `else if(word.compareTo(r.item)){` gives a compiler error that points to `r.item` and says it cannot be converted to a string. What should I do to solve this?

```
public void insert(String word) {
    root = insertItem(root, word);
}

protected TreeNode insertItem(TreeNode r, String word) {
    //base case
    if (r==null) {
        new TreeNode(new WordRefs(word));
    }
    else if (word.compareTo(r.item)) {
        r.left = insertItem(r.left, word);
    } else {
        r.right = insertItem(r.right, word);
    }
    return r;
}

public class WordRefs {

    private String word;
    private LinkedList<Integer> lineNumbers;

    public WordRefs(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        lineNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addLine(int lineNumber) {
        lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public LinkedList<Integer> getLineNumbers() {
        return lineNumbers;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = word + ":";
        for (Integer ii : lineNumbers) {
            result += " " + ii;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class TreeNode {
    WordRefs item;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(WordRefs item) {
        this.item = item;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }

    public TreeNode(WordRefs item, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.item  = item;
        this.left  = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your WordRefs class and your TreeNode class, i answered a question earlier with the same classes and havent seen them

Comment: I added the code for both, it tells me WordRefs cannot be converted to a string

Comment: i just put and answer use the getWord() method and its being compared to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your insert function should be something like this, you have to use the getWord() function from WordReft and it should be <= 0 to go to the left side and > 0 to go to the right

```
protected TreeNode insertItem(TreeNode r, String word) {
//base case
if(r==null){
 r =   new TreeNode(new WordRefs(word));
    }
else if(word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) <= 0){
    r.left = insertItem(r.left, word);
}else{
    r.right = insertItem(r.right, word);
}
return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it compiles now!

Comment: your welcome, good luck learning data structures, assuming that your learning data structures :)

Comment: edit just put r = into the if(r == null) you have to return r